# DropZone JS and Laravel Chunk File Upload failing

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, file-upload, dropzone.js

I have a simple Laravel Application where I am trying to upload video files (in GBs) on the server.

For Front-end I am using [DropZoneJS](https://www.dropzonejs.com/)

For Back-end I am using Laravel with [Laravel Chunk Upload](https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload)

I followed all the instructions given on [Controller settings](https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload/wiki/controller), [Route settings](https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload/wiki/routing), and [DropZone](https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload/wiki/dropzone).

It works flawlessly on Local (which is no surprise since it's just like copying files) but when I try it on the server, multiple requests are fired as expected but after some requests, all the requests are failing without any error.

Successful Request:

[image: Successful Request]

Failed Request:
[image]

```
<div id="my-awesome-dropzone"></div>
<script>
let myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
    url: "{{ route('admin.add_tutorials', ['course' => $course]) }}",
    paramName: "tutorials", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    chunking: true,
    method: "POST",
    maxFilesize: 40000000000,
    chunkSize: 1000000,
    parallelChunkUploads: true
});

myDropzone.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
})

myDropzone.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
})
</script>
```

I checked the settings in php.ini `upload_max_filesize` and all the other values are set correctly.

Please help here, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Similar issue happened in one of our project. We increased chunkSize, and it temporarily fixed the issue.